# Objects dissappearing from array in java

Tags: java, arrays, object, processing

I'm making a game similar to agar.io where a blob goes around and eats dots. I'm making it on my phone and you control the blob with your finger to collect the dots. I noticed that when I collect a single dot some random other dots dissappearing as well. I debugged some and found out that unless you collected the dots in the order that they were added to the array, any dot with a lower array order would be destroyed. Example: if you collected the dot added to the array 7th then dots 0-6 would dissappear, bit if you collected 1 then 2 and so on then no other dots would dissappear randomly. I created another simpler example to explore this problem. Now it's a simple screen with 5 circles. You can pick up and drag and drop any circle. I noticed the same problem where you drag a circle and other circles randomly dissappear even though there is no code to make them dissappear. My code is as follows:

```
// Drag n' Drop //

Objects[] box;
int objCount = 5;

void setup() {
    box = new Objects[objCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < objCount; i++){
        box[i] = new Objects(random(displayWidth),random(displayHeight),200);
    }
}

void draw() {
    background(170);

    for (Objects boxes : box) {
        boxes.display();
        boxes.dragging();
    }
}

class Objects {
    float x, y;
    float s;

    Objects(float tempX, float tempY, int tempS) {
        x = tempX;
        y = tempY;
        s = tempS;
    }

    void display() {
        ellipse(x, y, s, s);
    }

    void dragging() {
        if (dist(x, y, mouseX, mouseY) < 500) {
            x = mouseX;
            y = mouseY;
            s = 300;
        }
    }
}
```

I believe my problem may lie in the loop I use to call the display function of the box object, but I cannot find out any other way to make it work. Any help us very much appreciated. Thank you for your time. PS Im using processing to run this code.

- Kelton

Comment: Could you add the code that handles destroying the objects?

Comment: if destroying the objects is not working correctly, that is the code you should post - probaly an array is not the best to hold objects that will be deleted, I would consider using an ArrayList

Comment: where is the code that is triggered when you delete the objects? please post that too

Comment: @Dean This is code from my simpler example without anything for removing the bits. They simply dissappear for no reason. I decided to post the simple code so it was easier for people to understand. When I drag and drop the dots some of them randomly dissappear.

Comment: @JonnoHampson this is my simple example with no code to destroy them. They just dissappear for some reason. When I drag them around others just randomly dissappear until there is only one left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I'd like to thank you for I have never played with Processing before and you inspired me to download it!

There are quite a few things wrong that I'd like to point out and maybe steer you in the right direction. The main issue lies within your `dragging()` method you are not actually removing the objects you are just moving them to your mouse position, giving you the illusion they are being removed!

Anyway, as you said you were creating the game Agar.io, I would assume that you yourself should have your own `Blob`. For the sake of my Java brain I have switched what you called `Objects` to `Blobs`.

First off, the setup.

```
import java.util.*;
public static final int BLOB_COUNT = 10;
List<Blob> blobs = new ArrayList<Blob>();

// this is our blob, the one that displays in the middle of the screen
Blob myBlob = new Blob(mouseX, mouseY, 50);

void setup() {
    size(1000, 500);
    for (int i = 0; i < BLOB_COUNT; i++){
        blobs.add(new Blob(random(displayWidth/2),random(displayHeight/2),50));
    }
}
```

Notice how I am using `ArrayLists` rather than an array, this will make it easier for you to add and remove from the List.

Next, the draw() so this happens each frame.

```
void draw() {
    background(170);

    // refreshes the players blob wherever the cursor is! 
    myBlob.setX(mouseX);
    myBlob.setY(mouseY);
    myBlob.display();

    // display the other blobs on the screen
    for (Blob boxes : blobs) {
        boxes.display();
        boxes.dragging();
    }
}
```

Notice, we want to update our blob to the current position of the mouse!

Lastly, the Blob class!

```
class Blob {
    float x, y;
    float size;

    Blob(float tempX, float tempY, int size) {
        this.x = tempX;
        this.y = tempY;
        this.size = size;
    }

    void display() {
        ellipse(x, y, size, size);
    }


    void dragging() {
        if (dist(x, y, mouseX, mouseY) < myBlob.getSize()/2) {
            myBlob.setBlobSize(25);
            this.x = random(displayWidth/2);
            this.y = random(displayHeight/2);
        }
    }

    void setX(float x){
      this.x = x;
    }

    void setY(float y) {
      this.y = y;
    }

    void setBlobSize(float size) {
       this.size += size; 
    }

    float getSize() {
      return this.size;
    }

}
```

So now, we check in the dragging() method whether the blob is close to our blob, and if it is we want to consume that blob (which increases our mass) and then we want that blob to re-spawn to another location, well that's how most Agar.io games work, but of course this is entirely up to you. There is also much more accurate ways to calculate the area of the blob and determine whether two blobs are within touching distance, but I'll leave the maths to you.

Comment: thank you for the very detailed answer. I'm glad you had fun using processing. I apologise for some of the confusion as this is not the code for agario that I made but instead a small piece of code used to test the oddity of the blobs dissappearing. I do believe that arraylists are what I should be using because I need the array to be dynamically sized.  Thank you again for the answer and your time.